# ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

Tags: oracle

I have this query I am trying to run but I keep running into this error.  I am trying to do a `Where` clause that compares the data (BLOB column) to :var2 which is a blob object.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT max(id) 
INTO :var1
FROM table_name 
where data = :var2;
```

Any suggestions to why I would be getting this `ORA-00932` error?

I am comparing a `blob` to a `blob column`, shouldn't that be fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They aren't simple types and you need to use a function to compare them.

```
SELECT max(id) 
INTO :var1
FROM table_name 
where dbms_lob.compare(data,:var2) = 0;
```