# Error ORA-00932 when using a select with union and CLOB fields

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

First of all, this isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980038/ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-clob) question. If it is, sorry but I couldn't solve my problem by reading it.

I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

When I try to execute this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT TXT.t_txt 
  FROM CITADM.tb_avu_txt_grc GR  
 INNER JOIN CITADM.tb_avu_txt TXT   
    ON (GR.e_txt = TXT.e_txt and GR.u_txt = TXT.u_txt)  
 WHERE  TXT.u_lin_ord = 1
UNION
SELECT TXT.t_txt 
  FROM CITADM.tb_avu_txt_grc_cvd GRC  
 INNER JOIN CITADM.tb_avu_txt TXT  
    ON (GRC.e_txt = TXT.e_txt and GRC.u_txt = TXT.u_txt)  
 WHERE  TXT.u_lin_ord = 2
```

The selected field(t_txt) is of CLOB datatype. As you can see, it's the same column of the same table. This statement belongs to a bigger one, I've isolated the part where I'm having this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I believe the problem is the use of `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.  The `UNION` operator will combine the two sets *and eliminate duplicates*.  Since CLOB types cannot be compared, the duplicate elimination part is not possible.

Using `UNION ALL` won't attempt to do duplicate elimination (you probably don't have duplicates anyways) so it should work.

Comment: old question & answer but this worked for me today, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I *had* duplicates, I couldn't use UNION ALL. This solution work perfectly, thank you!

BTW:
This is imho the only correct answer, because UNION ALL and UNION are semantically different. If don't have duplicates at all, using UNION imposes an unnecessary sort overhead.

Comment: This should be comment.