# Getting error on queries with union

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I did union on 2 of my queries below but gets the error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.NAME, A.ADM_APPL_NBR, A.ADMIN_FUNCTION, A.STDNT_CAR_NBR, 
A.ACAD_CAREER, A.APPL_PROG_NBR, A.ADMIT_TERM, A.CHECKLIST_CD, A.DESCRSHORT, 
A.CHECKLIST_STATUS, TO_CHAR(A.STATUS_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
TO_CHAR(A.DUE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), A.COMM_COMMENTS, A.SEQ_3C, A.CHKLST_ITEM_CD, 
A.DESCR, A.ITEM_STATUS, TO_CHAR(A.UM_STATUS_DT_CL,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
TO_CHAR(A.UM_DUE_DT_CL,'YYYY-MM-DD'), A.RESPONSIBLE_ID 
FROM PS_UM_7902_VW2 A 
WHERE ( 1 = 1 AND EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1) 
AND ADM_APPL_NBR LIKE DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2) 
AND CHECKLIST_CD LIKE DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3) 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4 
 OR '' = :4 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.ADMIT_TERM = A.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT)) 
 UNION 
 SELECT B.EMPLID, B.NAME, B.ADM_APPL_NBR, B.ADMIN_FUNCTION, B.STDNT_CAR_NBR, 
 B.ACAD_CAREER, B.APPL_PROG_NBR, B.ADMIT_TERM, B.CHECKLIST_CD, B.DESCRSHORT, 
 B.CHECKLIST_STATUS, TO_CHAR(B.STATUS_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
 TO_CHAR(B.DUE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), B.COMM_COMMENTS, B.SEQ_3C, 
 B.CHKLST_ITEM_CD, B.DESCR, B.ITEM_STATUS, TO_CHAR(B.UM_STATUS_DT_CL,'YYYY- 
 MM-DD'), TO_CHAR(B.UM_DUE_DT_CL,'YYYY-MM-DD'), B.RESPONSIBLE_ID 
 FROM PS_UM_7902_VW2 B 
 WHERE ( B.EMPLID = :1 
 AND 1 = 1 and ADM_APPL_NBR like DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2)
 and CHECKLIST_CD like DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3) 
 AND B.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( B.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN B.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND B.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND B.ADMIT_TERM = B.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN B.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND B.TERM_END_DT);
```

Please help guys.

Comment: Remove columns one at a time until the query compiles.  Then fix the column or columns causing the error.

Comment: you mean the columns I am selecting?

Comment: Although each of your two queries has 21 columns, and their names appear to match, it seems at least one column has a different datatype in one query to the corresponding column in the other. (I'm assuming the two queries run individually.) One way to diagnose the problem is to remove columns until the error goes away.

Comment: By the way, you have mixed `or` and `and` conditions in your `where` clauses. Are you sure they are doing what you want?

Comment: You can't use plain UNION when one of your selected columns is a CLOB. See this duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17732879/3061852

Comment: The SELECT clause seems to be fine. You are fetching the same column names from the same view in the same order. Check if the columns passed to TO_CHAR functions are in fact DATE columns. If they are fine, then you issue is only in the WHERE clause. Compare the column data type and each input value.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: Im still going to test the sql once data is available, for your reference though - what i want is when EMPLID is provided and the rest is not, ADM_APPL_NBR and CHECKLIST_CD get every value, while CHECKLIST_STATUS is I or CHECKLIST_STATUS is C when term is current TERM. ADMIT_TERM when blank defaults to Current Term.

Answer (score 2):

Column `A.COMM_COMMENTS` and `B.COMM_COMMENTS` are CLOB. You can't union CLOBs.
One alternative would be do a `TO_CHAR(A.COMM_COMMENTS)` and `TO_CHAR(B.COMM_COMMENTS)`, then it should work.