# Queryset filtering by multiple FK attributes

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

My situation:

I have django model **HOST** and model **PACKAGE** (with name and version) which has FK on **host** model. Now I need to filter all **hosts** which have **packages** with certain **name** and certain **version**.. therefore something like `Host.objects.filter(name="best_package", version__in=['1.0','2.0'])`
This is all nice and easy, but I need to repeat this action for several packages so I would get host which has each of wished packages in one of the versions..

I tried two approached but both failed, first was applying **filter** above in the for loop, it was ugly but worked and as happy as I was I found out this isn't stable solution and some of my queries which I apply next **SOMETIMES** fails.. yes sometimes! As I said to my self I'm not going deeper in that hole of Django ORM magic I tried to build the query with Q. I ended up with following code

```
pckgs_query = reduce(
    operator.and_,
    (
        Q(packages__name=name, packages__version__in=versions)
        for name, versions in pckgs_dict.items()
    )
 )
hosts = Host.objects.filter(pckgs_query)
```

but unfortunately this isn't working properly, as I checked the SQL query it generates I'm sure it is looking for single PACKAGE object with all those parameters which of course does not exists... Is there somebody skilled enough to give me a hand? Really lost here and kind of wishing my app wasn't in django right now tbh

Thanks!

Comment: It is not working, because you restrict the *same* package. So you say that that package needs to have as `name` both `'best_package'` and `'other_package'`, hence from the moment you introduce two (different) names, this will always fail.

Comment: Don't you think, you should be using `or` operator instead of `and ` ?

Comment: @sonus21 than it would also include host which has only one of those

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in my real code its something like packages_set and its related manager to access all packages which are fk from the other side to selected model

Comment: @FilipM: exactly, but what basically happens is that it JOINs *once* with the related `Package` model, and then you start adding `WHERE` clauses on the related model.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work is because you each time restrict the same package. If the keys are thus `'best_package'` and `'other_package'`, you say that there should be a related package that has as `name` both `'best_package'` and `'other_package'`, but since the package has only one name, that will of course fail.

We can solve this in another way: we first filter the packages to retrieve all *packages* that match with an entry in the dictionary, and then *count* these, and thus check if the number of related packages is the same as the number of elements in the dictionary:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

pckgs_query = Q(
    *[Q(package_set__name=name, package_set__version__in=versions)
      for name, versions in pckgs_dict.items()],
    _connector=Q.OR
)

hosts = Host.objects.filter(pckgs_query).annotate(
    num_packages=Count('package_set')
).filter(
    num_packages=len(pckgs_dict)
)
```

This will thus only return the `Host`s that have *all* packages installed, since if a package is missing, then the `num_packages` will be less than `len(pckgs_dict)`.

Comment: @FilikpM: then it should be `package_set__name`, etc. and `Count('package_set'). But that does not matter.

Comment: hi, sorry but this is not working in a long run for me because my db does not support some of the sql queries generated from that, therefore i'm still looking for solution.

Comment: @FilipM: exactly what SQL is not supported. It only contains some filtering, an aggregate (`COUNT`), and a `HAVING` clause. As far as I know, this is standard SQL: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Comment: its causing inconsistencies in my app because of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980038/ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-clob therefore its not usable for me

Comment: @FilipM: looks like there is a type mismatch between the types of fields of the `name` and `version` of the `package_set`, and the ones in the dictionary.

Comment: Is it possible even if query finishes fine under certain circumnstances? calling print(hosts) fails but print(hosts.values_list('id') ends up ok