# Spring Auth Server JDBC implementation - error with Oracle DB BLOB

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm getting an ORA error when trying to use the packaged JDBC persistence classes from the new Spring Authorization Server v0.2.2 library with an Oracle 18c XE database. Specifically, from the Spring packaged `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` class, I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT id, registered_client_id, principal_name, authorization_grant_type, attributes, state, authorization_code_value, authorization_code_issued_at, authorization_code_expires_at,authorization_code_metadata,access_token_value,access_token_issued_at,access_token_expires_at,access_token_metadata,access_token_type,access_token_scopes,oidc_id_token_value,oidc_id_token_issued_at,oidc_id_token_expires_at,oidc_id_token_metadata,refresh_token_value,refresh_token_issued_at,refresh_token_expires_at,refresh_token_metadata FROM oauth2_authorization WHERE authorization_code_value = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB
```

The schema packaged with the Spring Auth Server library looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE oauth2_authorization (
    id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    registered_client_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    principal_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    authorization_grant_type varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    attributes blob DEFAULT NULL,
    state varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    authorization_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
    authorization_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    authorization_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    authorization_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
    access_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
    access_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    access_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    access_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
    access_token_type varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    access_token_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
    oidc_id_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
    oidc_id_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    oidc_id_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    oidc_id_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
    refresh_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
    refresh_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    refresh_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    refresh_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

From what I've read, Oracle won't let you use any kind of DISTINCT/UNIQUE/grouping functions with LOB columns, but this query seems to be pretty straight forward. Wondering if anyone has gotten the default Spring Auth Server JDBC persistence classes and schema working with an Oracle database or has any insights into a fix?

Comment: @dur This is not a duplicate of [ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589937/ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-blob) and should not have been closed. I am not implementing Oracle queries in my code. I am implementing the Spring Authorization Server library with JDBC persistence and I am asking for assistance from the Spring team or someone familiar with the library, because I am getting an ORA error from their code. I have tagged the question with the `spring-security` tag because the Spring team monitors this tag.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/480. I would say you have to customize your schema (using `varchar` instead of `BLOB`).

Comment: See also: [347](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/347), [413](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/413) and [387](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/387)

Comment: @dur thanks!  i just found that last night. i think that's what i need.